# How to filter the values of a model column, that don't exist in the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

Given an array of model ids:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I get an array of the ids, which do not already exist in the database? I can do:

```
ids.reject { |id| Model.exists?(id: id) }
```

but I don't want to make a separate database query for every id. What is the way to get the non-existent ids in a single database query?

Comment: Not sure about the RoR syntax, but the SQL way to do it is; Create a data-set containing [1,2,3] and then identify which don't exist in the target table...   `SELECT sample.* FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id) sample LEFT JOIN target ON target.id = sample.id WHERE target.id IS NULL`

Comment: @MatBailie +1 for providing a pure SQL solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like given below if you are using rails 4 or above

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
existing_ids = Model.where(id: ids).ids
ids - existing_ids
```

If you are using rails 3, you need

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
existing_ids = Model.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)
ids - existing_ids
```

Read more about `pluck` and `ids` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ids) respectively.

Thank you [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) for pointing me about `ids` method.

Comment: You can use `.ids` instead of `.pluck(:id)`

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. That was something new for me. I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR : If `ids` is the array of ids you want to check and MyModel is the name of your model then the following is an array of the ids that do not exist : `ids - MyModel.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)`

---

`MyModel.where(id: ids)` will return all records for `MyModel` that have an id matching one of the values of your `ids` array. But if you add `.pluck(:id)` will return an array of only the ids for those records. So `MyModel.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)` is the array of record ids that match your `ids` array values.

Then you can use the minus operator to make the difference of the two arrays. `array1 - array2` returns only the elements of array1 that are not in array2.

So putting everything together you get `ids - MyModel.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two things: you don't need the `all` for `pluck`, you can do MyModel.pluck(:id) directly and Sebin's answer is a bit more efficient, as it potentially instantiates a smaller array (haven't bench-marked it though).

Comment: @AlexPopov It seems you did not see my edits, but I had already edited my answer to make it more efficient exactly as you said in fact ;)